# Is it a standard practice to have a single application/controller writing to database

Tags: synchronization, software-design, data-synchronization, software-quality

I've been interviewed by some experienced engineer, when he strongly disagreed with some statements I said:

- Assuming full control over your applications, It's a standard practice to make writes-to-database exclusive to one single application or controller (not about multiple application instances, but different applications).
- Assuming full control over design, synchronization is better implemented using observer pattern than using polling from both ends.

I'd really like for some experienced engineers to enlighten me on those 2 main points, and point to me if I've been right/wrong about them.

Comment: Didn’t really understand your first point. If I have a couple of applications responsible for a different domain, each application will have a component who knows about the database and this component will access the database. It better be through an interface, which will be shared across all applications, but each application will do it separately. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: About the second point, this might help: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/102771/when-would-polling-for-events-be-better-than-using-observer-pattern/102781

Comment: @oren thanks for the comments and the link. About the first point, for example, having 2 different applications each with its separate logic and access, writing to the same table.